# Javascript variable name

Tags: javascript

I have attempted var name,here is my code:

```
var name = ("Type Name Here") {

}
```

I am just trying to make a Script like a Google Document where I have my scripts there so I can look at that if there is a bug in a script. When I run I get the error:

> Missing ; before statement

Please help me figure out what the problem is in my script.

Comment: Is that all of your code? If so, that is not valid syntax. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think you want `var name = prompt('Type Name Here');`.

Comment: You cannot do that. You have to create all variables like this: var name = “Type Name Here”; the semicolon is what was missing. Remove the {}

Answer (score 2):

Type the variable name where you have typed `name`.

On the right-hand side of the `=`, type the value you want.

`"Type Name Here"` is a string literal expression which will create a string value (the parenthesises are superfluous).

`{}` is an object literal expression which will create an object value (with no properties).

You can only give a value one value at a time.

```
variable_name = some_value
```

You cannot follow `some_value` with another value (hence the error message you receive where it expects an end of statement marker (`;`) between the string literal value and the `{` that follows it.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are trying to create a function. These are the valid options to do it:

```
function Test(arg1, arg2){ console.log('hello world'); }

var otherTest = function(arg1, arg2){ console.log('hello world'); };

var oneMoreOption = (arg1, arg2) => { console.log('hello world'); };
```

this is not the full set of valid syntaxes. [here is the official reference with the full details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)